# Catch response from coded google form

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

My task is try to catch response from Google Form that i generate from response of another form

This script create variable `message` using response on first form and call `formResponseOne(message);`

```js
function onSubmit(e){

  var response = e.response;
  var nameOfUser = response.getRespondentEmail();  
  var responseFromUser = response.getItemResponses();
  var message = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < responseFromUser.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = responseFromUser[i];
    var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var value = itemResponse.getResponse();

    message += title + ": " + value + ", ";
  }
  formResponseOne(message);
}
```

This code create new Form and set description from response from first form and set new trigger for this new form.

```js
function formResponseOne(description){
  var formUrl;
  var form = FormApp.create('Response1');
  form.setDescription(description);

  var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  item.setTitle('Request');
  item.setChoices([
        item.createChoice('Yes'),
        item.createChoice('No'),
    ]);

    ScriptApp.newTrigger('triggerForOne')
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();

    formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl();
}
```

This is a trigger that must work when i answer on second form, but it didn't work

```js
function triggerForOne(e){
  var formResponse = e.response; //ERROR HERE
...
}
```

Error in https://script.google.com/home/executions:

```
No response with id: 2_ABaOnueqKJjpWwVt15MXPXCpXvX3c5YIYLnmxbW3UgvP9Z0Sgw0W1a2dFiJ5K9wEtkaIm9M exists for this form.
```

Comment: In order to help please can you answer the following questions: 1) What is the task you are trying to acomplish? 2) Where is the event object `e` coming from in `triggerForOne(e)`? 3) When is `formResponseOne(description)` being called?

Comment: 1) It will be some sort of approve from several people. There are three people. First people request to do some stuff. Next must approve this. Next one must approve too, if second say "yes". All people use only Google Form. 2) It must coming from answer of second people(first who approve). 3)It is called by ```OnSubmit()``` of first Form, by first people. Thanks in advance for your answer! @RafaGuillermo

Comment: Can you please post your code that is building the second form with the response from the first form? Also, where are you receiving the error `No answer from this ID: `?

Comment: ```function onSubmit(e){
  var response = e.response;
  var nameOfUser = response.getRespondentEmail();  
  var responseFromUser = response.getItemResponses();
  var message = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < responseFromUser.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = responseFromUser[i];
    var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var value = itemResponse.getResponse();
    
    message += title + ": " + value + ", ";
  }

  formResponseOne(message);
}```     Error i see here: https://script.google.com/home/executions

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, i rebuild question and add code.

Comment: Is `triggerGorOne(e)` a function in the first form, or the second form?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, ```triggerForOne(e)``` in second form

Comment: Have you tried something like this:(I haven't included all of the details) `function sendForm(form1) {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(){
    google.script.run.sendform2(form2);
  })
  .sendForm1(form1);
}`  That way the second for doesn't get sent until the first server function sends a return back to withSuccessHandler.

Comment: @Cooper this is all done within Google Forms not HTML forms through HtmlService. I've narrowed down the problem to this; Form1 has a function which creates Form2. Form1 then creates an installable `on submit` trigger for Form2 which attempts to run a function from the script bound to Form1. On Form2 submit it tries to run `triggerForOne(e)` *which is bound to Form1* and passes it the event object related to the Form2 submit event. The value of `e.response` is a response for Form2 and not Form1, so the `No response with id ### exists for this form` error appears in the Stackdriver logs.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, i think that we can narrowed down whole problem to that: if human create form, we **can** use event trigger ```onSubmit()```. If form and trigger created programmatically, we **can't** use event trigger ```onSubmit()```

Comment: It seems this way. Even creating a new script and binding it to the new form using the Apps Script API, creating a trigger for the new script is where the hurdle lies. I feel like there is an easier way to complete the task you are trying to accomplish though, a 3-tier Form and Trigger system seems very convoluted for an approval system. Do you have to use Forms? Could a Sheet not be used instead, for example? Either way it seems that what you're trying to do here isn't possible.

Comment: The more interaction you want the more likely you are to need HTML forms I hardly ever use Google forms. At some point you’re just going have to learn how to use html forms. Or pay someone else to do it for you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65346812/1595451