# Installable trigger to fire script in a different form?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I'm trying to run a script that is connected to one form (A) when a different form (B) is submitted. I have a series of different forms that are similar and needs to run the same script, so instead of copying the code to each script I wonder if this is possible.
I successfully made an installable trigger function in A, pointing at B. I have granted permission when prompted.
When i post B, the script in A fires, and I get this in the log:

```
Exception: No response with ID 2_ABaOnudSFDkNQOL2Xn4fNOmT95GrTotEW8LSjxfI5qf6qceDN5hD5CHKqNT5D4G_DdONWq0 exists for this form.
    at onFormAnswerSubmit(Kod:40:20)
```

The line (Kod:40:20) that halts is the line that fetches the posted data:

```
  var items    = e.response.getItemResponses();
```

Is this supposed to work or is it impossible to pass posted data from one form to a script in a different form?

Or is there something more I can do in the trigger? Like forcing a pass on of e. or something?
Here is the trigger I created:

```
/**
 * Creates a trigger for when a different form is posted that runs a function in this script (run once)
 */
function createOtherFormTrigger() {
  var formID = FormApp.openById("XXXXX"); // form B
    
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormAnswerSubmit') // a function in this script, in form A
      .forForm(formID)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}
```

Comment: the forms are actually not connected to any sheet, I'm using script on the form side to  dump data into google docs and send emails.

Comment: You don't need to add (bind) the script to the other Forms.  Any Apps Script file can affect any other Form as long as everything is in the same account.  All you need is the Form file ID to get any other Form, and do something with that Form.  Apps Script code can open a Form by it's file ID.  The script file that is affecting the Form doesn't need to be bound to the Form that it opens.  If you want to create a new response in a Form (Add data to the Form)  programmatically, that is possible.  You don't need to create a trigger in the other Forms.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the logic a bit:

### The function fired on trigger should be contained in the same script like the trigger.

Sample code to create a formSubmit trigger for form B:

```js
//run this once
function createOtherFormTrigger() { 
var formB = FormApp.openById("XXX");   
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormAnswerSubmit') // a function in this script, in form B
      .forForm(formB) //the active form is Form B
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}
function onFormAnswerSubmit(e){
   var formB = e.source;
   var items = e.response.getItemResponses(); //items of the latest form response of form B
   var formA = FormApp.openById("XXXX"); // Form A 
  ... 
  // do what you need to do with form A
}
```

The code above will create trigger that fires when a form response for form B is being submitted. Thereby it is not important either the script is bound to form A, form B or is [standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone). Actually, it might make mosst sense to implement those functions in a standalone script, to make sure that they don't interfer with other form submit triggers you might have in a form-bound script.

Comment: Thanks, that did id - I made it into a standalone. Thanks for helping me work out the logic!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Anywhere where I put `e.response` I get the same error. It looks that the only workaround is to use a stand alone script instead of a bounded script.

Answer (score 0):

I just understand the problem.

So if you want to catch the response from the form submission, you need to bound your script to the form. To do that, go to your form edit view, then click the three dots, then open script editor.

If you done that previously, try do it again and make sure your script is there. In my case, the first time I open the script editor from the Google Form, it doesn't bound the script. So when I did it the second time, it opens a new script editor with blank template. After I copied my script to the new one, it works perfectly.